# How to transforme matrix to matrix containing identity matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to get transformed array contains identity matrix from n*m array using numpy/scipy.

```
from n*m matrix
array([[ a,  b,  c,  d, e, f],
       [ g,  h,  i,  j, k, l],
       [ m,  n,  o,  p, q, r]])

to

array([[ 1,  0,  0,  a', b', c'],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  d', e', f'],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  g', h', i']])
```

There are identity matrix front of array.I want those array.

Gauss jordan algorithm and Gaussian elimination algorithm can transforme matrix to matrix that contains identity matrix. But that can't transforme any n*m matrix and there are no transforming functions in numpy/scipy.

Anyone know good solution?

Comment: What transformation steps are allowed?  The ones you also use when inverting a matrix?

Comment: all ok, of course inverting a matrix is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gauss algorithm can still be applied because it can be done by combining only lines of the input.  The number of additional values at the end of the given line does not matter then.

Example steps without checking for zeros (i. e. how to do it if all values are ≠ 0):

```
a b c d e f
g h i j k l
m n o p q r

1 b/a    c/a    d/a    e/a    f/a     (that's I/a)
0 h-bg/a i-cg/a j-dg/a k-eg/a l-fg/a  (that's II - I*g/a))
0 n-bm/a o-cm/a p-dm/a q-em/a r-fm/a  (that's III - I*m/a)

etc.
```

I hope the way is clear now.  You have to check for zeros, of course, (and maybe swapping lines) to avoid dividing by them, but that's the normal way of applying Gauss.

Comment: oh, I forgot the basic because I absorbed in looking for suitable function. It's nice solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If numpy.linalg is allowed, then

```
import numpy as np
n, m = A.shape
assert n < m
B = np.linalg.solve(A[:, :n], A[:, n:])
C = np.hstack((np.identity(n), B))
```

will do your job.

Comment: thanks but it dosen't work (ex. 3*6 sized matrix). Its code raise _LinAlgError: Singular matrix_.

Comment: My transform is `C = inv(A[:, :n]) * A` which means that rows are combined without permuting columns. Sorry if this is not general enough for you.